# Call Go command through .net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, go

I have .Net MVC Web Application and I need Json Result from GoLang[github] project. How can I execute command or How can I get result from Go to .Net MVC application.

Is it Possible? I am new in "Go".

If it is impossible to call "go run main.go" [kind of calling] from Web Application, then please suggest any other solution to get result.

Comment: Are you looking for [Process](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process?view=netframework-4.8)

Comment: `go run main.go` will be horribly inefficient. You should just build it and call the compiled binary from your .NET app.

Comment: @Adrian...I agree can you please elaborate that how to call compiled binary file from .NET app?

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use [processstartinfo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo?view=netframework-4.8). Another way would be to use docker. If you have access to `dockerd` you can make an API call to start a new docker container and make the container stream the output once it's done.